# C# WebApi serializar/deserializar XML con namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, serialización, webapi, namespace

Estoy construyendo un servicio web el cual debe aceptar la request en formato XML.

El XML de entrada es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:cashoutrequest xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/v1_0">
    <sending>51999283264</sending>
    <receiving>51999283333</receiving>
    <amount>4</amount>
</ns2:cashoutrequest>
```

El código del controlador junto con el método que utilizo para deserializar la request son los siguientes:

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public IHttpActionResult Execute()
{
    HttpContent content = this.Request.Content;
    string xml = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    // Serializa xml request
    cashoutrequest cashoutrequest = FromXML<cashoutrequest>(xml);

    return Ok(cashoutrequest );
}

private T FromXML<T>(string xml)
{
    T @object = default(T);
    try
    {
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            @object = (T)new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return @object;
}

// Clase cashoutrequest
[Serializable()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.example.com/v1_0")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.example.com/v1_0", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class cashoutrequest
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string sending { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string receiving { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public byte amount { get; set; }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que las propiedades del objeto `cashoutrequest` no logran ser deserializadas correctamente (todas terminan siendo NULL).

Me percate que esto puede deberse a que el nodo raíz del xml posee como prefijo el namespace: `<ns2:cashoutrequest/>`, dado que realice la serialización de un objeto mock `cashoutrequest` y el xml obtenido fue diferente.

```
cashoutrequest cashoutrequest = new cashoutrequest
{
    sending = "5199928324",
    receiving = "51999283111",
    amount = 15
};
string xml= Serialize(cashoutrequest);

// XML obtenido en serialización
<cashoutrequest xmlns="http://www.example.com/v1_0">
    <sending>51999283264</sending>
    <receiving>51999283111</receiving>
    <amount>15</amount>
</cashoutrequest>
```

Espero alguien pueda aconsejarme a solucionar mi problema.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que indicar en las propiedades que no aplique el namespace que define en el nodo root, para eso usas  `[XmlElement(Namespace="")]` en las propiedades, algo como esto:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.example.com/v1_0")]
public class cashoutrequest
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace="")]
    public string sending { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Namespace="")]
    public string receiving { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(Namespace="")]
    public byte amount { get; set; }
}
```

Usando este codigo

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
                        <ns2:cashoutrequest xmlns:ns2='http://www.example.com/v1_0'>
                            <sending>51999283264</sending>
                            <receiving>51999283333</receiving>
                            <amount>4</amount>
                        </ns2:cashoutrequest>";


        cashoutrequest result = FromXML<cashoutrequest>(xml);

        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", result.sending, result.receiving);
    }

    private static T FromXML<T>(string xml)
    {
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

puedo validar que deserializa correctamente